# If two individuals are selected from the room at random, what is the probability that those two individuals are NOT siblings?

Tags: probability

In a room filled with 7 people, 4 people have exactly 1 sibling in the room and 3 people have exactly 2 siblings in the room. If two individuals are selected from the room at random, what is the probability that those two individuals are NOT siblings?

Say the seven people are A, B, C, D, E, F, & G:

A has siblings B & C

B has siblings A & C

C has siblings A & B

D has sibling E

E has sibling D

F has sibling G

G has sibling F

The ways for =) are $3*(AE, AD, AF, AG)=4*3$

The total ways of choosing two people is 21.
12/21 is not right.

A. $5 / 21$

B. $3 / 7$

C. $4 / 7$

D. $5 / 7$

E. $16 / 21$

Comment: You missed cases DF and similar.

Comment: Choose the persons one by one. Find the probabilities of the mutual exclusive events that 1) the first chosen has 1 sibling and the second chosen is this sibling 2) the first chosen has 2 siblings and the second chosen is one of these siblings.

Comment: DF, DG, EG,EF yeah